# Microsoft VBA to compare two columns and display error message

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets "Sheet A" and "Sheet B", "Sheet A" contains some data and  "Sheet B" contains all the data. So if i "Sheet A" doesn't have any data which in not present in Sheet B i want to show message.

**VBA Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myRng As Range
    Dim lastCell As Long

    'Get the last row
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Debug.Print "Last Row is " & lastRow

    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
        For Each d In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
        For Each d In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Don't ask us to guess...

Comment: try vlookup, might be easier then using vba.

Comment: or `countif` or an array formula maybe.  You haven't said if this is the contents or part of the contents.  The `instr` would imply that it could be ABC in 123ABC456, but not sure.  An indication of what, when and where and any other background would assist.

Comment: Everytime user can't go and check vlookup i.e I have written VBA Code in which on button click it will change the color of that which are not present from sheet B

Answer (score 0):

You could try this formula if you have column based data. This would go on Sheet A beside your data (A1 is your data, B1 is the formula) and lookup Sheet A Column A with That of in sheet B (matchRange = Sheet B , Column x).

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LookupValue,MatchRange,0)),"Yes","No")`